# Angular show class active on Navbar

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I know I can use `[routerLinkActive]="['active']"`, in fact I'm using it and works fine when I click the button on navbar and redirect's to `example.com/home`, but if I use only `example.com`, the is no active class, `/home` and only the url are the same component, how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can use a redirect in your routing module

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "", redirectTo: "home", pathMatch: "full" },
  { path: "**", component: PageNotFoundComponent, pathMatch: "full" }
];
```

> Explanation:

It will redirect from `example.com` to `example.com/home`. That way the `routerLinkActive` will properly highlight the selected route.

Take a look at, [Angular Scaffolding](http://www.abhijit-kar.com/angular-scaffolding/). It has been done the same way. Try removing the path and you'll see.

> Or even better, listen to route events:

[Demo](http://www.abhijit-kar.com/)
[Source Code](https://github.com/abhijit-kar/abhijit-kar.github.io/blob/portfolio/src/app/header/header.component.ts)

> Something Along the lines of this:

```
constructor(
  private router: Router
) {
  router.events.subscribe((event: RouterEvent) => {
    this.navigationInterceptor(event);
  });
}
```

> And then do this

```
navigationInterceptor(event: RouterEvent): void {
    if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
      this.currentUrl = event.url;

      const route: Route = this.currentUrl;

      this.loading = true;
    } else if (
      event instanceof NavigationEnd ||
      event instanceof NavigationCancel ||
      event instanceof NavigationError
    ) {
      this.loading = false;
    }
  }
```

> Then use the route url in template, something like this

```
<a mat-tab-link matFocus="true" *ngFor="let route of routes" [routerLink]="route.url" routerLinkActive [active]="currentUrl === route.url" (click)="currentUrl = route.url" #tabs>
     {{route.label | uppercase}}
</a>
```

> Take a look at the source code for better understanding

Comment: Yes, redirect is an option, but what if I don't want redirect?

Comment: @JaumeSastre I have the solution, let me update the answer